# ASP.NET Core Get Data and load then in boostrap model

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried several times to load the related folder for a certain cabinet when an anchor element is clicked as shown in the below code:

This is the view which loads all cabinets when a user clicks on the link it should view the cabinet folders, the issue the first time it successfully loads the data, but if I try to click any other button the application will not execute the related stored procedure:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="cabinets_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Ref No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Upload Date</th>
                <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Cabinet cabinet in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@cabinet.RFCode</td>
                    <td>@cabinet.NameEn</td>
                    <td>@cabinet.Description</td>
                    <td>@cabinet.CreateDate</td>
                    <td>
                        //This is the anchor element
                        ***<a asp-controller="Cabinet"
                           asp-action="GetCabinetContents"
                           asp-route-BranchID="@cabinet.BranchID"
                           asp-route-CabinetID="@cabinet.ID"
                           data-toggle="modal"
                           data-target="#cabinet_contents_modal"
                           class="btn btn-default cabinet_contents_btn"
                           title="Cabinet Contents">
                            <i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i>
                        </a>***
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default add_folder_btn" title="Add Folder" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new_folder_modal"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default delete_cabinet_btn" title="Delete Cabinet"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is where the folder will be displayed:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cabinet_contents_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="cabinet_contents_modal_header">Cabinet Contents</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="loadCabinetFolders"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
@section LoadCabinetFolders { 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.cabinet_contents_btn', function (e) {
            $('#loadCabinetFolders').empty();
            $('#loadCabinetFolders').load('@Url.Action("_CabinetFoldersPartial")');
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

Last but not least, here is the action method

```
public IActionResult GetCabinetContents(int BranchID, int CabinetID)
    {
        return PartialView("_CabinetFoldersPartial", this.cabinet.GetFolders(1, CabinetID));
    }
```

your help is much appreciated
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`function loadCabinetFolders(){
    $('#loadCabinetFolders').empty();
    $('#loadCabinetFolders').load('@Url.Action("_CabinetFoldersPartial")');
}`

change your script code to a function like above and try to call on click function using html tag in the  tag, where your are calling

"$('body').on('click', '.cabinet_contents_btn', function (e)" this code.

Comment: In the layout page

Comment: Can you please check whether parameters are properly passed ?
I think you should hit this method GetCabinetContents()

Comment: For the first time, yes, if i click View Cabinet Contents for the second time, nothing gets executed I checked SQL Profiler

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your effort, all i had to do is change the jquery function on click to:

```
$('#cabinet_contents_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            $('cabinet_contents_modal .modal-body').empty();
        });
```